# I did not initialize a variable yet I still receive an output

Tags: java, initialization

Here is my code:

```
class Xyz{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      first fobj = new first(10);
      for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
         fobj.add();
         System.out.printf("%s",fobj);
      }
   }
}

class first{
   public int sum=0;
   public final int num;
   first(int x){
      num=x;
   }

   public void add(){
      sum+=num;
   }

   public String toString()
   {
      return String.format("sum = %d" ,sum);
   }
}


output:
sum=10
sum=20
sum=30
sum=40
sum=50
```

In the class `first` I didn't initialize a variable named "sum" but I still get output. Can someone explain that to me?
asgfafgalsdfkjsaflkasflaskfalskfajlskfaskfaslkjflaskfaslkflasjkf.

Comment: What's this? `public int sum=0;`

Comment: You have initialized it to 0.

Comment: sorry thats my mistake its int sum;

Comment: int variables still initialize to 0. Look into [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226405/why-do-instance-variables-have-default-values-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Instance members are automatically initialized to default values, [JLS-4.12.5 Initial Values of Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created ([§15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), [§15.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10)):
>
> ...
>
> ```
> For type `int`, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Class and instance data members are automatically defaulted to the all-bits-off value for their type (`0` in the case of `int`), even if you don't do it explicitly. Since `sum` is an instance data member, it's implicitly defaulted to `0`.

This is covered by [§4.12.5 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):
>
> - For type `byte`, the default value is zero, that is, the value of `(byte)0`.
> - For type `short`, the default value is zero, that is, the value of `(short)0`.
> - For type `int`, the default value is zero, that is, `0`.
> - For type `long`, the default value is zero, that is, `0L`.
> - For type `float`, the default value is positive zero, that is, `0.0f`.
> - For type `double`, the default value is positive zero, that is, `0.0d`.
> - For type `char`, the default value is the null character, that is, `'\u0000'`.
> - For type `boolean`, the default value is `false`.
> - For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, all the member variables are automatically initialized to their default values at the time of object creation even if you don't do it yourself. Default value of `int` is `0`.